# Multiple ZStack controlling zIndex

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Imagine a Grid (n x n) squares. Those squares are ZStacks. It contains an optinal piece (In this case a circle). If I offset that piece over another ZStack it gets hidden by the other ZStack.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is a chess game.  Imagine the Circle() being a piece. 
This was my initial attemp:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var circle1Offset: CGSize = .zero
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                Color.blue
                Circle().fill(Color.black)
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .offset(circle1Offset)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { value in
                            self.circle1Offset = value.translation
                        }
                )
            }
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
            ZStack {
                Color.red
            }
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)

        }
    }
}
```

Also I tried to add an overlay() instead of using a ZStack. Not sure which is more precise for this case, but unluckily i can't add an "optional" overlay like so:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var circle1Offset: CGSize = .zero
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Color.blue
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                .overlay(
                    Circle().fill(Color.black)
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        .offset(circle1Offset)
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture()
                                .onChanged { value in
                                    self.circle1Offset = value.translation
                            }
                    )
            )
            Color.red
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)

        }
    }

    func tileHasPiece() -> Circle? {
        return Circle() // This would consult my model
    }
}
```

But as I said, I don't know how to use tileHasPiece() to add an overlay depending on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put all board static elements below, and all figure active elements above, as in below modified your code snapshot. In such case everthing will be in one coordinate space. (Of course calculation of coordinates for figures is out of this topic)...

```
struct FTContentView: View {

    @State var circle1Offset: CGSize = .zero
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // put board below
            VStack {
                Color.blue
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                Color.red
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
            }

            // put figure above
            Circle().fill(Color.black)
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .offset(circle1Offset)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        self.circle1Offset = value.translation
                    }
                )
        } // board coordinate space
    }
}
```